# fetching wrong value from databse while using SqlDataReader

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[carcallvalidation]
@carid nvarchar(100)=null
as begin SET NOCOUNT ON;  select t.TBarcode, t.Paid,t.Status,t.DelDate from Transaction_tbl t where TBarcode=@carid declare @transid integer=null
select @transid= t1.transactID from Transaction_tbl t1 where TBarcode=@carid
if(select count(k.transactid) from KHanger_tbl k where k.transactid=@transid)>0
begin
return 1 end  end
```

while executing this i am getting out put like this:

```
TBarcode             Paid  Status      DelDate
-------------------- ----- ----------- -----------------------
57173621345          1     0           NULL  while i am checking this value using vb.net code like
```

this:

```
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
Dim payd As Integer
dr = cmdcarvalidation.ExecuteReader   While dr.Read
If dr("Paid") Is DBNull.Value Then payd = 0 Else
 payd = dr("Paid")  If payd = 1 Then  MsgBox("Payment Done") Exit Sub End If End If  End While
```

but payd values is taking as -1..but in database i am getting this value as 1.then how i am getting -1 value..

Comment: First of all, please, take some advantage from the marvellous code-display auto-corrections of VS and write your code as VB.NET expects conditions to be written (one statement per line). Regarding your problem, it seems like you are using DBNull.Value wrongly, as far as, presumably, the "Paid" column is of integer type and its "blank-record value" is not null (but -1). This might be the reason for the behaviour you see. In any case, it has to do with your DB and the way in which the values are stored there. If the connection string is right, SQLDataReader just delivers what is in there.

Comment: so what i have to change..??

Comment: IF (not completely sure) my assumption is right, replace "Is DBNull.Value" with "= -1".

Comment: sir if the paid value=1 then take dr("Paid")= -1,,so how i can get my exact out put..

Comment: ?! I don't get your last statement. Your heading condition (the one making payd = 0), is based on something which, presumably, will never occur (no value in this column will be DBNull.Value); replace it with what is most likely the value in the situation you are intending to track, that is -1. If dr("Paid") = -1 Then payd = 0  Else 'all the remaining code, which might be dr("Paid") = 1 or equal to any other value. You understand that -1 and 1 are different integers, don't you? Also please, can edit your code and make it clearer?

Comment: sir in my database paid  value is 1..so i given code what ever you said

Comment: if paid is 1 i want to show message MsgBox("Payment Done"),,but this time i never get paid is equal to one,,if the database value is 1,,then am getting value by my code is -1

Comment: This does not make any sense. If you get -1 is either because the given field in the DB has this value or because the field is empty and the default value for this column is -1. Take a look at your DB and make sure that the information there is right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36610/discussion-between-user2674855-and-varocarbas)

Answer (score 0):

in databse data type of paid is bit,,so in code we should check the value is True of false,,not 0 or 1

Comment: I am afraid that this is not a solution (a generally-applicable one useful to someone). This is just the confirmation that you didn't analyse the information properly (neither post it here). If you want to make this a proper question/answer (useful to someone at all), you should rewrite both parts (answer and question) to highlight the problem you found (getting -1s), what proved to not be useful (relying on Null), what was the final problem (values stored as bit/boolean... not sure still from this answer) and how you solved it. If you don't want to do that, perhaps should delete this Q/A.